# MPMoviePlayerController gives endless loop on tapping 'Done'

Tags: cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I try to get a MPMoviePlayerController to work, but have a strange problem. When playing I click the done button and there seems an infinite look triggered:

> 2012-02-13 15:18:04.395 iDomsPortalDev[7376:12203] playbackFinished.
>   Reason: User Exited 2012-02-13 15:18:04.395 iDomsPortalDev[7376:12203]
>   playbackFinished. Reason: User Exited 2012-02-13 15:18:04.395
>   iDomsPortalDev[7376:12203] playbackFinished. Reason: User Exited

I use the following notifications on starting:

```
- (void) showMoviePlayer {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];      

    id appDelegate = (iDomsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //[[self navigationController] presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:[appDelegate movieController]];    
    [[appDelegate moviePlayer].view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:[appDelegate moviePlayer].view];
    [[appDelegate moviePlayer] setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];    
}
```

and the following listeners:

```
#pragma mark - Movieplayer feedback
- (void)willEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willEnterFullscreen");
}

- (void)enteredFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"enteredFullscreen");
}

- (void)willExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willExitFullscreen");
}

- (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"exitedFullscreen");
    iDomsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iDomsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    [[appDelegate moviePlayer].view removeFromSuperview];
    [[appDelegate moviePlayer] release];
    [appDelegate setMovieController:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {
    iDomsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iDomsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    NSNumber* reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    switch ([reason intValue]) {
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Ended");         
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Error");
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: User Exited");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [[appDelegate moviePlayer] setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Only the PlayBackFinished selector is called (infinite times), so there must be something stupid I do (running in the simulator with iOS5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it seemed to have been setting the fullscreen option which caused it:

```
[[appDelegate moviePlayer] setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```